# How to easily calculate permutations on large vectors $(\omega_1, \omega_2, ...)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, permutations, random-variables

I need to calculate the events corresponding to the number of ones in 10 dice rolls.

When $X$ is a r.v. for the number of ones, then this produces events:

$(X=0)=(0,0,...,0)$
$(X=1) = \{(1,0,...,0), ..., (0,0,...,1)\}$
...
$(X=10)=\{(1,1,...,1)\}$

Listing all these as sets proves to be slightly challenging.

So is there a formula for finding the permutations in these sets or specifically the number of permutations in each set (in order to be able to formulate the probability distribution of $X$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X=0$ and $X=10$ the answer is clear. In the other cases we are talking about permutations with repetition. The formula for $X=k$ is $$\dfrac{10!}{k!(10-k)!}.$$

Note that if $0'$s and $1'$ are labelled then the number of possible positions is $10!.$ But since we do not distinguish between $1'$ we must divide by $k!,$ wich is the number of permutations of $1'$s if they were labelled. For the same reason applied to $0'$s we divide by $(10-k)!.$

We have to note that  $$\dfrac{10!}{k!(10-k)!}=\binom{10}{k}.$$ (It works also for $k=0,10.$) We have a formula form the sum. It is

$$2^{10}=(1+1)^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}.$$

Comment: Could you explain what's the name of this formula?

Comment: And this only gives the number of permutations in $(X=k)$, but does not actually enable listing all of them?

Comment: I have editted the answer to get the sum. Also to explain the formula a little. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Also can I somehow calculate the cardinality of the entire set of events, i.e. $|(X=0)|+|(X=1)|+...+|(X=10)|$? Or do I simply have to sum the above formula for each $k$?

Comment: I have written the sum. It is $2^{10}.$